# <global-forwards> in struts 2

Tags: struts2

we are converting our application from Struts 1.2 to 2.16. I ahve added the requried jars and now i am converting struts_config.xml to struts.xml. Below is i struts-config.xml

```
<struts-config>
 <global-forwards>
        <!-- Default forward to "Welcome" action -->
        <!-- Demonstrates using index.jsp to forward -->
        <forward name="welcome"  path="/Welcome.do"/>
        <forward name="family"   path="/Employee.do"/>
        <forward name="line"     path="/Owner.do"/>
   </global-forwards>
    <action-mappings>
         <action path="/Welcome" forward="/pages/welcome.jsp"/>
         <action path="/Employee" forward="/pages/employeejsp"/>
         <action path="/Owner" forward="/pages/owner.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>

</stuts-config>
```

I am not able convert Global_forwards to global_results. when trying to access the page  getting a blank page and its not throwing any error.  Did add devmode still no luck.

Could any one please help me .

Thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be forwards but redirects.

Answer (score 0):

```
<forward name="welcome"  path="/Welcome.do"/>
      <forward name="family" path="/Employee.do"/>
      <forward name="line" path="/Owner.do"/>
</global-forwards>
```

to

```
<global-results>
     <result name="family" type="redirect">Employee</result>
     <result name="line" type="redirect">Owner</result>
</global-results>
```

for action mapping

```
<action-mappings>
         <action path="/Welcome" forward="/pages/welcome.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>
<package name="test" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="Welcome" class="org.xyz.Welcome" method="welcome">
         <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
         <result name="input">/register.jsp</result>
     </action>
</package>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did that i am getting a blank page. My url would be www.xxx./Employee.do?emp_id=34. I even added struts.properties file with struts.action.extension=do to configure .do extension.

Comment: from jsp call like '<a href="Employee?empId=<s:property value="empId"/>">Get Emp by ID</a>`

Comment: there is no class with Family. According to struts 1.2 when ever there is /Family in url the page is forwaded to family.jsp and there java code is called. And the jsp do not have the struts tags. we have no plan of adding it.